# ES6 in Google Web-starter-kit - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-web-starter-kit

After removing the line `"only": "gulpfile.babel.js",` in the `.babelrc` file,
I created a class:

```js
export default class App {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Cool")
  }
}
```

Then, I imported it in the first line of the default `main.js`, and called it at the end:

```js
import App from './app'
//...
(function() {
  'use strict';

  // default stuffs ...

  // Your custom JavaScript goes here

  const app = new App();

})();
```

It threw me this **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(…)**,
and the error point to the first line of the `main.js` where the statement `import App from './app'` is.

Cross posted here: https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/issues/904